# How to call a SOAP GetListItems service on SharePoint InfoPath form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, forms-services, infopath-rules

I want to sort column alphabetically from the SharePoint list's column on InfoPath form drop-down, on the basis of two fields on form load. I am trying to call the SOAP web service on InfoPath form data connection by http://sharepoint.dev.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?

On list name I have applied the list name, on the view name I have added the lists correlation id. What should be the other remaining parameter(query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, and Web Id) and How I can pass the parameter in sample column in this? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

query,viewfields,rowLimit is the same as CAML Query parameter, Web Id is the current web Id and can be leave as empty, you could refer the parameter set in the sample below which call lists.asmx in C#:

[SharePoint List Web Service GetListItems](https://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2009/12/sharepoint-list-web-service.html)

Comment: I am adding the CAML query but it returning me below

Comment: can't see the detailed information, could you please repost ?